# Compile time warning when ignoring returning object

Tags: java, api, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I know that Java normally allows not caring about the returned object if present from a method, but in this case, I want to make sure that the user of an Api adds the returned instance to a list, otherwise it will be executed straight away.

Plain Java:

```
Runnable someTask() {
    ...
}

someTask(); // ok
```

Should be

```
Runnable someTask() {
    ...
}

addToExecutionList(someTask()); // ok
someTask(); // gives warning
```

Is there a way to prevent this with say a compile time warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent this with say a compile time warning?

No. There's no way of forcing a caller to use the return value of a method. Something like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) may have an option for reporting it as dodgy code, if that helps you.

Comment: Hmm... Can you think of a runtime solution?

Comment: @Theodor: Not really. I was considering something with a finalizer, but that would be *really* hacky, and wouldn't always be appropriate.

Comment: No, I agree that hacky solutions should be avoided in APIs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Compile time warnings are only for the most common errors.  It is normal practice to ignore return values.

What you can use is a static analysis tool like find bugs, checkstyle or IntelliJ's static analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a parameter to `someTask` and let `someTask` take care of adding itself to that list:

```
void someTask(List<Runnable> executionList) {
  // ...
  executionList.add(task);
}
```

But of course, that will not prevent from passing a nonsense list to that method.

If you want to make sure, that the runnable is *always* added to a very special list, then you should change the api so that the user won't be able to call `someTask` but will see some sort of "factory" that creates the task *and* adds it to that list. Which should be internal so that no one can remove the newly created task from that list (and so on ;) )

Comment: the first solution could be implemented as a `AbstractTask` with `List<Runnable> executionList` as a constructor parameter and `executionList.add(this)` in its constructor, and the non-sense list could be checked at runtime, might not catch all bugs, but some.