# Compiler error when result of method is ignored/not used

Tags: java, logging, compiler-errors, compilation

I want my coworkers to not ignore result of method, f.e. in builder, when You do not build object. I have fluent api that will log message. If someone will not used final method to log, the log message will be gone. How I can Warn, or compile error when such case occurs. F.e.:
Success case- message will be logged in log file/console:

```
logbuilder.text("").level("").log();
```

Failure case- message will NOT be logged in log file/console:

```
logbuilder.text("").level("");
```

I would like compiler to fail in such case.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to creating a rule, e.g. with ArchUnit that catches that. But in general you cannot achieve that, especially not using the regular compiler, only with with static code analysis.

Comment: Have a look at [How can ignoring of return value be marked in Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55669689/3890632) and  [Compile time warning when ignoring returning object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779224/3890632) and [Using annotation to ensure that value returned by method is not discarded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3614150/3890632)

Comment: May I ask? Why would you even want to create a LogBuilder class? There are more than enough logging frameworks out there, and it seems your logbuilder makes the code more complex without giving any obvious benefit. What am I missing?

Comment: It just simple example of tought. I have high requirements about logging.

Comment: @masterdany88 I doubt your requirements can't be satisfied with something like Log4j or Slf4J, which  would bemuch simpler than the code you've shown